# Multiline text with ellipsis using flex. A solution which is compatible across browsers?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
**Multiline text with ellipsis using flex. A solution which is compatible across browsers?**

The below solution works for only single line. I want to know if it is possible using the flex property.?
```

//style applied to the span which contains the label

```
.span{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 226px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

label {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

How can i get this working for multiline text. ?

Comment: Generally, the problem is not related to flexbox, and ellipsis on multiline text is particularly tricky as their is no simple cross browser solution as of today